# Can't install golangci-lint locally

Tags: shell, go, linter, golangci-lint

I'm using RHEL 8.6 and my Go version is the following:

```
$ go version
go version go1.18.3 linux/amd64
```

I'm trying to install locally `golangci-lint` and none of the described ways in the [documentation](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/#local-installation) are working.

What I tried:

First:

```
$ curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.46.2
golangci/golangci-lint info checking GitHub for tag 'v1.46.2'
golangci/golangci-lint info found version: 1.46.2 for v1.46.2/linux/amd64
golangci/golangci-lint info installed /home/acabista/go/bin/golangci-lint
$ golangci-lint --version
bash: golangci-lint: command not found...
```

Second:

```
$ go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.46.2
$ golangci-lint --version
bash: golangci-lint: command not found...
```

Am I missing a step? How can I make this local installation work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If golang-ci has properly been installed, the issue is most likely that the installation directory is not in your `PATH` environment variable. Calling golang-ci this way should then work:

```bash
${GOPATH}/bin/golangci-lint --version
```

or

```bash
/home/acabista/go/bin/golangci-lint --version
```

To chek what is happening exactly you can check the content of the `GOPATH` environment variable. Its content defines where binaries are installed when a `go install` like command is run.

```bash
echo $GOPATH
```

You need to check also what is the content of the `PATH` variable, this one defines in which directory the shell looks for binary to execute:

```bash
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem installing `golangci-lint`. I resolved it by adding this `PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin/` to my `~/.bashrc` file and run `source ~/.bashrc` on the terminal.

To verify, check the version by running the command from terminal `golangci-lint --version`

Reference:
[Found the solution from this github discussion here](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/discussions/1898)

Answer (score 0):

Install it this way to avoid error

```
curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sudo sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.54.0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo snap install golangci-lint
```

This works for me